# Why does my code run quicker on my phone than my laptop?

Tags: python, performance, python-3.x, precision

I'm beginning to learn python and I've just finished my first project, which was the collatz sequence, which is "If n is even, divide it by 2 to get n / 2. If n is odd, multiply it by 3 and add 1 to obtain 3n + 1. Repeat the process until you reach 1."

Here is my code, it's not very long:

```
import sys

def integer():     #Asks for input and checks whether positive integer

        while True:
                number = input("Enter a positive, whole number:")
                try:
                        number = int(number)
                        if number > 0:
                                break
                        else:
                                raise ValueError
                except ValueError:
                        print("That's not right! \n Please enter a positive, whole number")
        return number

number = None

def collatz(): 
        global number
        print(number)
        while number > 1:
                if number % 2 ==0:
                        number = number // 2
                else:
                        number = number * 3 + 1
                print(number)

while True:               #loop so that you can try again
        number = integer()
        collatz()
        repeat = input("Try again? Y/N").upper()
        while repeat != "Y" and repeat != "N":    #Only Y/N are valid
                repeat = input("Try again? Y/N")
        if repeat == "N":
                sys.exit()     #end program if N selected
        else:
                pass           #Reloops to try again
```

I ran this code on an app called "QPython3" on my Google Pixel XL (Up to 2.4 GHz), running Android 7.1.1 and also my base model MacBook Pro (Retina, 13-inch, Early 2015)(2.7GHz).

The MacBook took multiple minutes to reach 1 when I used an absurdly large number such as 10^100, but my phone did it almost instantaneously.

I don't understand why this would be the case. Shouldn't the proper computer be better in every way?

(If you want to give feedback on the overall effectiveness of my code, that is appreciated, but probably not worth your time as I'm very new and would likely not understand things too well. I'm just trying to make code that works at this stage)

Comment: I guess your phone has python2 and uses 32 bit integers, while your laptop uses python3 with arbitrary precision ints.

Comment: @TamasHegedus QPython uses 3, unless she has a very old version. And note her calls to `print`.

Comment: I'd say profile it on your Mac to see where most of the time is being spent. That will be your biggest clue.

Comment: And are you sure your phone did it instantaneously? How did you enter `10^100`? Did you actually type 100 zeros, or did you type `10^100`? If I type `10^100` in QPython, if parses it as `110`. Your Mac may parse it differently.

Comment: Can you please specify exactly the input for this? I'm on Python 2.7 and leaving `input` as it is (i.e. not defaulting back to `raw_input`) I can get `10e100` to execute in a fraction of a second but `10^100` is invalid. Switching to `raw_input`, `10e100` and `10^100` are invalid. (I know they're not the same thing but both large numbers)

Comment: An other possible explanation is that QPython uses some optimized stdout handling. Are you sure the two programs run the same way? `print(number)` prints the same numbers?

Comment: Running the same code in Python 2.7 on my 2013 MacBook Pro, an input of 10e100 returns almost instantly; same with an input of 100.....0 with Python 3. The code is fine; something is wrong with your execution environment if it is taking minutes to complete.

Comment: Perhaps it would be helpful if your code output the number of steps needed to get to 1, so you can be sure they are doing the same thing.

Comment: with an input of 10 ** 100, my pc returned in .006 second after 1855 iterations, on python 2.7.8

Comment: As a side note, raw_input is a very bad way to show a MCVE because you also have to give the inputs.  It's much easier to just put the input directly in the code, so you can prove a problem exists. We have no proof here. What were the exact inputs?